# how to display the data from database in tables in aspx page without using Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a table in aspx page and I have some drop down list where I select the value which stored into the database. But now I want to display that dropdownlist values from database into aspx page table that I already created in design page. I am just getting the problem while displaying the data in table. I did google for it but it shows me aspx.cs coding where the table created in .cs page but I want tables in aspx page. Without using HTML and gridview can anybody help me out?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do you expect to show a page without using `HTML`

Comment: if u dont want grid view then u have to use LIST VIEW, and call that database value inside listview,

Comment: @3dd: i mean without using HTML in server side c#. Beacause I already have a table in aspx page

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use HTML table there are two possible way to bind the data 
1) bind the data in server side using c#, that you have already seen in some example
2) use Jquery ajax to to get the data in Client side and in success function you can bind the data to your table.

Comment: No, I already have a table in aspx page so I dont want to use server side table. Can you please tell me how to use 2nd option

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ajax call to get the data.

```
<table id="tbDetails" width="800">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Userid</td><td>UserName</td><td>Location</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Default.aspx/GetDetails",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (msg) {
         $.each(msg.d, function (index, obj) {
             row += "<tr><td>" + obj.UserId + "</td><td>" + obj.UserName + "</td><td>" + obj.Location + "</td></tr>";
         });

         $("#tbDetails tbody").append(row);
     }
   });
```

Server side code - create a webmethod and call the same from your Ajax call

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<UserDetails> GetDetails()
{
    //Write your database logic here and add items in list
    List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();
    details.Add(new UserDetails() { Location="aaaa", UserId="adv", UserName="fdfds"  });
    details.Add(new UserDetails() { Location = "bbbb", UserId = "hhhh", UserName = "aaaafds" });
    return details;
}
```